# Html.RenderPartial causing a loop

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have problem using html.RenderPartial.
For example: lets take the Account model, I took the LogOn view and copied it to a partial view and added it to the master page. When I run the app and the partial view of LogOn is open, using an ActionLink to another View from the same Model for example the Register view causing a loop and the web sticks.

The combination of these 2 commands cause a loop:

```
{ <%Html.RenderPartial("LogOn"); %>

<%Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account");%>}
```

Does anyone know how can I solve it?

Comment: Show the `controller` code..

Comment: Put it like { <%Html.RenderPartial("LogOn"); %> }

<%Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account");%>

Comment: the same controller when you open new MVC 2 web app visual studio 10, i didnt make changes to it.